# Using state monad without "get" function

Tags: haskell

In [this](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html) nice article about lenses Gabriel Gonzalez writes this code:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.Trans.State

strike :: StateT Game IO ()
strike = do
        lift $ putStrLn "*shink*"
        boss.health -= 10
```

but later on writes

```
newState^.boss.health
```

I know that in order to modify the `State` monad (here is the `StateT` monad transformer) you need to get the state using the `get` function, do something with it, and then use the `put` function. But here the author does not use these functions. Also in the second example he uses the `^` operator which means that to use the `boss` lens you need a `Game` value. But he does not do that in the first example. How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's look at the line `boss.health -= 10`. `-=` is [defined](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/src/Control.Lens.Setter.html#-%3D) in the `lens` package as:

```
(-=) :: (MonadState s m, Num a) => ASetter' s a -> a -> m ()
l -= b = State.modify (l -~ b)
```

Two points about this definition:

1. It doesn't use `get` / `put`, but [`modify`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Lazy.html#v:modify), where `modify f` is equivalent to `get x >>= \x -> put (f x)`
2. The first argument is `ASetter' s a`. A lens, in particular `boss.health` which the article used, works. The operator says "I'll subtract from the value in the state using the lens you pass".

Comment: Explaining my formatting edit: we don't use `\`\`\`` for code blocks; we use 4 spaces. Also, the language is automatically chosen from the tags. If you need to override the automatic decision for any reason, you can give the language by placing an HTML comment of the form `<!-- language: ... -->` before each code block. This is usually only necessary for language agnostic and multilingual questions.